# Question about the proof of $Ord(a) = Ord(a^{-1})$ where $a$ in a group.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Suppose $Ord(a) = n$ and $Ord(a^{-1}) = m$. Assume $m < n$. Hence $a^n(a^{-1})^n = a^{n - m} = e$. Thus $n \mid n - m$. But that's impossible.

I was wondering if the contradiction could mean $m \ge n$ instead of $n = m$? Why is $m > n$ impossible?

Comment: The assumption $m < n$ was taken without loss of generality. The $m > n$ case is exactly symmetric to this case and just wastes space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The contradiction does only imply $m\geq n$, but then applying the same argument to $a^{-1}$ and $(a^{-1})^{-1}=a$ shows that $m\leq n$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $ord(a)=n$. Then $$1=(aa^{-1})^n= a^n(a^{-1})^n=(a^{-1})^n.$$
If there is $m<n$ s.t. $(a^{-1})^m=1$, then $$1=(aa^{-1})^m=a^m$$
which contradict $ord(a)=n$. Therefore $ord(a)=ord(a^{-1})=n$.